# объединить один массивов php

Tags: php

> пробывал array_merge, implode и еще несколько вариантов но не смог

```
$pattern_cat = '/cat src="(.+)?f=s/u';
$cat = array();
preg_match_all($pattern_cat, $subject, $cat);
print_r($cat);
Array
(
    [0] => На главную
    [1] => Товары
    [2] => Балкон
    [3] => Сад
    [4] => Цветы
)
php
```

Comment: 1) что в итоге должно получится? 2) где у вас пачка массивов? вижу только один =)

Comment: Должно получится Array
( [0] => На главную/Товары/Балкон/Сад/Цветы) это типа парсер он проходит по товарам и берет значения по регулярке но я их не могу сделать один

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern_cat = '/cat src="(.+)?f=s/u';
$cat = array();
preg_match_all($pattern_cat, $subject, $cat);
$cat = array(implode($cat,'/'));
print_r($cat);
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает